# Implicit functions and related differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-function

I'm seeking guidance in derivation of implicit equation solutions to second degree differential equations.In the example below, differentiating twice just produced a tangle of terms which did not obviously lead to the required result.

Example: If 
$$y^3 +3yx +2x^3 = 0, $$
prove that $$x^2(1+x^3)y'' - (3/2)xy' +y =0$$

Comment: If you want to prove that equality holds, you just need to find y'' and y' and plug them in, then check that booth sides are equal.

Comment: Please can you rewrite that equation in MathJax code so it is easier to read. There is an instruction sheet for this at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I've tried the "obvious" method suggested above, but it does not seem to work. Is something else (eg change of variable) required?

Comment: The implicit method should work, but you can also solve for $$ y = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{x^6+x^3}-x^3}}-\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{x^6+x^3}-x^3}$$

Comment: plugging y=x/t -t into the original equation does indeed solve it, but I still can't see an easy way to proe the differential equation easily.

Comment: What do you mean by prove it? If you showed $y$ works, you are done.

Comment: To clarify, putting y=x/t -t into thei implicit equation yields a quadratic in t cubed, which leads to the expression for y given by you above.To answer the question I need to show that your expression satisfies the differential equation, or alternatively that the implicit equation implies the differential equation. Both of these seem to involve yearly messy differentiation so which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrow ideas from the numerical variant of Cardano's method for cubic equations.
Set $y=2\sqrt{x}\sinh(u)$, then
\begin{align}
0&=y^3+3xy+2x^3\\
&=2x\sqrt x(4\sinh(u)^3+3\sinh(u))+2x^3\\
&=2x\sqrt x\sinh(3u)+2x^3
\end{align}
$$\\~\\
\implies u=-\frac13\text{asinh}(x^{3/2}),
~~
u'=-\frac12\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}=-\frac12(x^{-1}+x^2)^{-1/2},
~~
u''=\frac14\frac{-x^{-2}+2x}{(x^{-1}+x^2)^{3/2}}
$$
and on the other side
$$
\left(\frac{y}{2\sqrt x}\right)'=\cosh(u)u',~~\left(\frac{y}{2\sqrt x}\right)''=\sinh(u)u'^2+\cosh(u)u''
\\~\\
\implies
u'\left(\frac{y}{2\sqrt x}\right)''=u''\left(\frac{y}{2\sqrt x}\right)'+u'^3\left(\frac{y}{2\sqrt x}\right).
$$
This is a linear ODE in $y$, as $u$ and its derivatives are solved as functions of $x$.
Now insert $u', u''$, apply the quotient rule, and simplify.

---

Observing the coefficient structure, one could first collect the terms as
$$
\left(\frac1{u'}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt x}\right)'\right)'=u'\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt x}\right).
$$

---

As $(x^{-1/2}y)'=x^{-1/2}y'-1/2x^{-3/2}y=x^{-3/2}(xy'-\frac12y)$, the last formula results in
$$
\left(2\sqrt{x^{-1}+x^{-4}}\left(xy'-\frac12y\right)\right)'
=\frac1{2x\sqrt{1+x^{-3}}}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt x}\right)
\\~\\
-\frac{x^{-2}+4x^{-5}}{\sqrt{x^{-1}+x^{-4}}}\left(xy'-\frac12y\right)
+2\sqrt{x^{-1}+x^{-4}}\left(xy''+\frac12y'\right)
-\frac1{2x\sqrt{1+x^{-3}}}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt x}\right)=0
\\~\\
-(x^3+4)\left(xy'-\frac12y\right)
+2x(1+x^{3})\left(xy''+\frac12y'\right)
-\frac{x^3}{2}y=0
\\~\\
2x^2(1+x^3)y''+[x(1+x^3)-x(x^3+4)]y'+2y=0
\\~\\
x^2(1+x^3)y''-\frac32xy'+y=0
$$
which is indeed the claimed differential equation.

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks, this was a tough question from the 1903 Tripos !

Comment: Great! +1. At least I don't have to suffer anymore trying to fix my own attempt